# Changing git branch while working with eclipse (what's proper order)?

Tags: eclipse

my problem is that sometimes I change git branch while working live in eclipse. But I do not know what should I do (in what order to to, to don't make mess in both projects).
So my procedure is:

1. eclipse is open (working on some problems)
2. git change branch
3. eclipse > selecting projects and clicking to refresh
4. work on eclipse, continue job

Is it all right or I should use first Clear&Build and then refresh projects? What do you think, is it important witch order do this while changing branch ? Please help because I am working with friends on big project and I do not want break anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a particular branch and you want to preserve whatever it is you have been doing, you should add or commit those changes first (`git add` or `git commit`) to that branch before changing to a different branch.

If you have the same projects in both branches, then refreshing the projects after changing branch should be fine, but ideally followed up with a clean/build.

If you want to be really safe, you can first close the projects before changing branch, then refresh and re-open them after changing branch.

Comment: Safest to refresh first, although I think clean/build should do a refresh anyway (not 100% sure though). I usually refresh first then clean/build.

Comment: I also need to restart Eclipse in order for the pipelines to show up correctly.